# SOLR Search - Is terms handler based auto suggest is efficient?

Tags: solr, autocomplete

Lets say I would like to display suggestions to the user as he types in the search box.
I have to fetch data from 4 columns - name, brand, cat, subcat.

use cases : puma, puma shoes, shoes, sports shoes puma, running shoes puma

After lots of try with different tokenizers, analyzers and filters, I am finally getting correct data with /terms handler. I am basically getting desired data from 4 separate calls for each fields A, B, C, D. And then combine data in PHP and send back as a ajax response.

I think its not the correct way since I have to make 4 separate calls on each key up ???

Can someone efficient and standard way to get auto suggestions ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While indexing you can create one copy field "xyz" and then copy the values of 4 columns - name, brand, cat, subcat into "xyz" field.

Use the expected tokenizers, analyzer and filter on this field and the use this new field in /terms handler.

Now you wont have to make 4 different call but now you can use only one call and get the desired results.

I have used this approach in my previous engagement and it was working perfectly fine.

Hope this will help you and let me know if it does...

Comment: Thanks Jayesh. I was adopted same architecture but I used wrong regex that time and later on I adopted another architecture looking for correctness.